# After NDK update, app is crashing on 3d file open

Tags: c++, android-ndk

I am facing this weird issue

We use NDK to use CPP libraries to render 3d object in android application. We have supported few file formats which are 3 dimensional. On of the file format get crashed while opening file only in release version.

We read geometrical data used NDK+JNI to handle it, CPP create hoops scene which uses opengl.

The thing that is only changed it NDK...

App work smooth in debug mode, in release mode if we set debuggle flag to true. it also works well.

Upon research  I know release build is optimized version of debug build and that where it is going wrong?

I am adding bug report

Things I tried

1. Reduced NDK update from 25 to 24.... base ndk version was 21.
2. Took previous code opening algorithm(old from git)
3. once I make debuggable release build everything works so i am not able to debug issue
4. There are some opengl related stuff in logcat

Comment: You need to reduce your codebase until you know in which part of your code the problem is. Then create a minimal, reproduceable example and add it to your question. Also provide the exact error messages. Without being able to see your code and try it out, it is impossible to give any more advice.

Comment: Code crashing when you turn on release mode tends to be the result of poorly written code that access memory it shouldn't. You should learn about [native postmortem debugging](https://source.android.com/docs/core/tests/debug/native-crash)